# Reverse proxy on Elastic Beanstalk to forward a subdirectory to subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nginx-reverse-proxy

We use Elastic Beanstalk for our frontend: https://tutorspot.co.uk. We also have a Wordpress blog at https://blog.tutorspot.co.uk but I'd like that to be available at https://tutorspot.co.uk/blog. I'm trying to configure a reverse proxy in Nginx on EB but am not having any luck getting the app deployed with the config.

I don't want to override the entire Nginx configuration, just extend it to include a new location block for the `/blog` path.

Here's the config I'm trying to get working:

```
location /blog/ {
   proxy_pass https://blog.tutorspot.co.uk;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

The [Elastic Beanstalk docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) suggest this should go in a `*.conf` file in `.platform/nginx/conf.d/`, however I'm running into the following issue when deploying the new config:

```
Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-xxxxxxxxxxx'. Aborting the operation.
```

I'm unsure whether this is the correct config and it's just in the wrong place, or whether the config itself is incorrect. For example, does the `location` block need to be wrapped in either a `server` or `http` context?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**NB 1:**
In production, we're using Amazon AMI, however, I'm taking this opportunity to upgrade us to Amazon Linux 2.

**NB 2:**
Here's the folder structure showing the location of the config file relative to `.ebextensions` etc.:

[image]

Comment: I think this error is not from nginx. Something in your `.ebextensions` or platform hooks failed. Have you explored logs to try to locate more detailed error message?

Comment: So the deployment succeeds with only `.ebextensions`, but as soon as I introduce `.platform`, it fails

Comment: [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-linux-platform-nginx.html) they use a similiar config. In the example Application they place the `.conf` under: `.platform/nginx/conf.d/beanstalk`. When placed under `conf.d` ngnix raises the error `[emerg] 13246#0: "location" directive is not allowed here in /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/01_custom.conf:1`

The example Application works for me. But I'm not able to make my own application work